# How to use conditionals with filters in R

Tags: r, tidyverse

I've seen quite a few posts on here about conditional filtering, but I can't seem to fit one to my example.

Using R, I am attempting to take this dataframe

```
original_df <- 
tribble(
  ~name, ~grade_level, ~assessment_level, 
  "A", 0, "pre read",
  "A", 0, "step 0",
  "A", 0, "step 1", 
  "A", 0, "step 2",
  "B", 1, "pre read",
  "B", 1, "step 1",
  "B", 1, "step 2",
  "C", 2, "pre read",
  "C", 2, "step 1",
  "C", 2, "step 2"
)
```

and filter it using these conditions

```
conditions: 
  if grade_level == 0 then filter(assessment_level == "pre read" | assessment_level == "step 0")
  if grade_level == 1 then filter(assessment_level == "step 1")
  if grade_level == 2 then filter(assessment_level == "step 2")
```

I need the final dataframe to look like this.

```
final_df <- tribble(
  ~name, ~grade_level, ~assessment_level, 
  "A", 0, "pre read",
  "A", 0, "step 0",
  "B", 1, "step 1",
  "C", 2, "step 2"
)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define the conditionals within the filter using something like

```
original_df %>% 
  filter((grade_level == 0 & assessment_level == "pre read") | 
         (grade_level == 0 & assessment_level == "step 0")   | 
         (grade_level == 1 & assessment_level == "step 1")   |
         (grade_level == 2 & assessment_level == "step 2"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option, using the premise of an inner-join:

```r
fltrs <- tibble(grade_level = c(0, 0, 1, 2), assessment_level = c("pre read", "step 0", "step 1", "step 2"))
inner_join(original_df, fltrs, by = c("grade_level", "assessment_level"))
# # A tibble: 4 x 3
#   name  grade_level assessment_level
#   <chr>       <dbl> <chr>           
# 1 A               0 pre read        
# 2 A               0 step 0          
# 3 B               1 step 1          
# 4 C               2 step 2
```